# How to transform XML / JSON file into documents in Lotus Notes?

Tags: xml, json, xpages

I have a big XML file with data of a lot companies and I like to convert this XML file to documents in my notes database. I want 1 document for each company. What would be the most easy way to do this? I downloaded a tool called Oxygen to read the data and I was able to create a JSON file of the XML file. I thougt maybe it is easier with JSON, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Martin, actually the easiest way is to use the sax parser to read the file (you said it is big). SAX is available in LotusScript and Java. It will fire events for each element (and end of), so you just need to create a new document when your start element happens and close it when it is finished. Pretty straight forward in both languages.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) in Java or [here](http://totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html#6.1.2) Just replace the system.out.println with doc.replaceitemvalue

Answer (score 1):

For reading XML, I use www.nsftools.com/tips/XmlNodeReader/ it brings the nodes in quickly. Once you read the node, you can put the value into a NotesDocument.

The best way I've found to create JSON is via http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/release.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=543656F34C821A2A862576650054BDC2

Answer (score 0):

This isn't what you've asked for but it might be an alternative. I'm not aware of any tool or anything inbuilt that will take XML and generate domino documents from it. However the below link goes through using server side javascript to pull in an XML and the end result is displaying it in an XPages data table control.

might help:

http://xpagesblog.com/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=3939DB27A4536248852578CB00667264

Answer (score 0):

If you received an XML file I wouldn't take the time to convert it to JSON with all it's  own drawbacks and differences you might get after conversion.

As previously told you should use an saxparser to parse the content. If you wrap it up in to a nice factory pattern you could easily extend it later on.

for instance

```
public class XmlDocumentConverterFactory(){
   public static AbstractXMLTDocumentConverter getConverter(String form) throws unsupportedDocumentTypeException {

 // get sax parser
      AbstractDocumentConverter converter = null;

     if("Company".equals(form)){
       converter =  new CompanyDocumentConverter();
     }else if("Contact".equals(form)){
       converter = new ContactDocumentConverter();
     }else}
       throw unsupportedDocumentTypeException("A Document of type "+form+" is not supported");
     }

     SaxParser parser = SaxParser.getInstance();
     converter.setParser(parser);    
     return converter;
   }
}

class abstractXMLToDocumentConverter{
  protected SaxParser parserInstance = null;

  public NotesDocument parseDocument(XMLDocument doc);
  public void setParser(SaxParser instance){
     this.parserInstance = instance;
   }


}

// these classes should implement the eventhandlers used by the parser
// they also need to implement the only method from their parent.
// when you want to import an xml document simply call factory.getConverter(yourform).parse(xml). 
class ContactDocumentConverter extends AbstractDocumentConverter(){}
class CompanyDocumentConverter extends AbstractDocumentConverter(){}
```

This way if you ever need to do the same again in the future you only need to add an extra else statement to the factory and create a new DocumentConverter class. Easy as pie.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an idea to put the xml or json file ,not sure if json will work, in the root of the html part of the domino server.

And use some sort of feed reader to create the documents. You will need a form with the fields or change them in your xml so you can use a form you already have.

I assume you want the data in a existing app.

I don't have any code handy, sorry.

But Simon has a good suggestion. And Stevens suggested tutorials are worth looking into.

Hope it helps. Personally i am interested to know if you succeeded and of course how you did it.